# "Don't Care" fields in multiset keys

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, multimap, multiset

I have a compound data type like:

```
struct Key {
    optional<int> a;
    optional<int> b;
    optional<int> c;
};
```

I also have a multiset, `multiset<Key>`. For example, it contains

```
{1, 2, 3}
{1, NULL, 3}
{NULL, 2, 3}
{NULL, NULL, 3}
```

I want to get all the objects in this multiset that match `{1, 2, 3}`. But there is catch: `NULL` fields should match with anything. For example, `{1, 2, 3}` matches with `{1, NULL, 3}`.

I tried to defined a comparator (`<`) that ignores NULL values. For example `{1, NULL, NULL} == {NULL, 2, 3}`. But it does not follow the *weak strict ordering* and it gives me wrong results.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't. In the worst case you have to fetch all the elements. Might just as well store the keys in a vector and try to match each one.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is even more serious than not following *weak strict ordering* rules. Your *equality* will not even be an equivalence relation: { 1,NULL,3} matches {1, 2, 3} and {1, 4, 3}, but {1, 2, 3}  does not match {1, 4, 3}. My conclusion is that you cannot rely on any standard container to meet your matching requirement with *catch all* values.

If you only want to store them, you should try to use an `unordered_set` or `unordered_multiset` because it will allow you to store the value without any problems. But you will have to manually implement a method for searching the container for a match.

**Beware**: I do not advise you to subclass a standard container (it is generally a wrong idea because they were not designed to allow derivation, have no virtual destructor...), but instead to include one in a custom class and delegate storage to it.